# How to detect the event of the closure of your website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to detect when the user closes the browser while my website is active
Since I am storing data in my local storage, I need to know when this event takes place in order to delete that data that I previously saved in local storage.
I am working with onbeforeunload to be able to capture the events, only this is activated when you press "f5", close the browser and close the page, I need to know how to validate so that it is only activated when I am closing the browser, could you help me?
I leave the small fragment of code that I implement, it is worth mentioning that I am working with React

```
function App() {


window.onbeforeunload = function(evt) { 
 localStorage.clear(); return '';
}


return (...)
}
```

Comment: Just use session storage instead of local storage.

Comment: The session storage limits you to being able to open multiple pages of the same domain in exchange for the local